# jpa one to one relationship issue when persist

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 models with one to one relationship

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Form_Item_Production")
public class FormItemProduction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "item_id", nullable = false)
    private Long itemId;

   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name = "shift_lookup_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
   private AppLookup appLookup;

   getter and setter
}
```

The other one

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "App_Lookup")
public class AppLookup {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "Lookup_Id", nullable = false)
    private Long lookupId;

    @Column(name = "Lookup_Name", length = 30, nullable = false)
    private String lookupName;

    getter and setter
}
```

When I try to persist to save the formitemproduction values

```
public boolean insertItem(List<FormItemProduction> f) {
for (FormItemProduction i : f) {
    System.out.println("A" + i.getAppLookup().getLookupId());  // prints the correct id of applookup
    i.setItemId(null);

    entityManager.persist(i);
}

entityManager.flush();

return true;
}
```

I get this error

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.mamee.factory.security.entity.AppLookup
```

From my understanding this is unidirectional one to one mapping so I don't quite understand why I'm getting the error detached?

Answer (score 0):

You have `itemId` which can't be `null`.

```java
@Column(name = "item_id", nullable = false)
private Long itemId;
```

and you actually set `itemId` to `null`

```java
i.setItemId(null);
```

So this line

```java
entityManager.persist(i);
```

Is not able to persist your data.

Comment: from my understanding, in order to persist itemid should be null so hibernate will consider it as a new record and use insert query

Comment: @ArnoldCristobal a new record from an existing `FormItemProduction` refers to a same `AppLookup` which break `@OneToOne` relation.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing from:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "shift_lookup_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private AppLookup appLookup;
```

to:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "shift_lookup_id", insertable = true, updatable = true)
private AppLookup appLookup;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have set cascade to ALL:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Which means you are cascading all operations down to the related field `AppLookup`.

You can set cascade to none, and you will no longer get your error, but no db operations  will be executed for `AppLookup` field.

Comment: `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)` is already set ... What are you talking about ?

Comment: You can set cascade to none

Comment: he never detachs `AppLookUp` object or interacts with it